# RWLock using boost shared_mutex, unique_lock and shared_lock

Tags: boost, synchronization, rwlock

I am tring to implement a RWLock interface

```
interface IRWLock
{
    void acquireLockShared();   //< LockRead.
    void releaseLockShared();   //< UnLockRead.
    void acquireLockExclusive();    //< LockWrite.
    void releaseLockExclusive();    //< UnLockWrite.
};
```

by using `boost::shared_mutex`, `boost::unique_lock` and `boost::shared_lock`.

The problem I have is that `boost::shared_lock` / `boost::unique_lock` are using RAII and should be one instance per thread (not shared as I need). I didn't managed to break acquire and release in two separate actions as I need.

Can this be solved somehow ?

Comment: How do you intend to use this interface? Anyway, "lock" classes are especially for RAII-style locking of `Lockable` concepts - if you don't need them, just call `shared_mutex` methods directly: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex